# I am getting a key error in my constructor, and I am not sure why?

Tags: python

I wrote this code:

```
def __init__(self, text, k):
    self._k = k
    self._model = {}
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        if len(text) > k:
            string = text[i] + text[k]
            self._model.setdefault(string, {})
        else:
            string = text[i] + text[i + k - 1]
            self._model.setdefault(string, {})
        for j in self._model:
            if j == string:
                if len(text) > k:
                    self._model.setdefault(text[k], 0)
                    self._model[j][text[k]] += 1
                else:
                    self._model[j].setdefault(text[i + k], 0)
                    self._model[j][text[i + k]] += 1
```

and I am getting this error:

```
File "markov_model.py", line 142, in <module>
    _main()
 File "markov_model.py", line 127, in _main
    model = MarkovModel(text, k)
  File "markov_model.py", line 30, in __init__
    self._model[j][text[k]] += 1
KeyError: 'a'
```

I just added some if statements regarding the length of k, as I figured that was the issue, but it is not so I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: You have three lookups on that one line, so it's hard to say which exactly is causing the problem. One of the things you're doing a lookup on though doesn't have an `'a'` key, but you're trying to get an `'a'` key. Do some debugging to find out what the problem is.

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug this without a working example. You need to make a [mre]

Comment: It can only be the `…[text[k]]` access causing the problem – presumably because you meant to use `setdefault` on `self._model[j]` instead of `self._model` right above. Why are you looping over a dict to find one key in it, though? `self._model[j]` is just a slow way of getting `self._model[string]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you've got a typo:

```
                self._model.setdefault(text[k], 0)
                self._model[j][text[k]] += 1
```

should be:

```
                self._model[j].setdefault(text[k], 0)
                self._model[j][text[k]] += 1
```

right?  At least just glancing at the code I assume the reason for the `setdefault` is so you can access that element on the following line.  :)